# Items in localStorage are removed after page reload in NgShoppingCart using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I have an Angular (8.0.0) project.

I've added this library to implement a shopping cart in Angular:
[NgShoppingCart](https://github.com/devconcept/ng-shopping-cart)

After I've added it in **app.module** like explained [here](https://devconcept.github.io/ng-shopping-cart/guide/get-started) I added these lines of code in one component:

```
  constructor(private cartService: CartService<TourCartItem>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  add() {
    const item = new TourCartItem({id: 1, name: 'My item'});
    item.setId(9);
    item.setName('Test item');
    item.setPrice(10);
    item.setQuantity(10);
    this.cartService.addItem(item);
  }

}
```

Everything works when I add an item, I see this in localStorage:
[image: 1]

but after I reload the page the items are reset:
[image: 1]

This is my **app.module**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ShoppingCartModule.forRoot({
      itemType: TourCartItem,
      serviceType: 'localStorage',
      serviceOptions: {storageKey: 'ToursCart', clearOnError: true},
    }),
    CoreModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production}),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [CoreComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    if (!environment.production) {
      console.log('app');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my custom class **TourCartItem**:

```
export class TourCartItem extends CartItem {

  uuid: any;
  description: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  image: string;
  quantity: number;
  data: any;

  constructor(itemData?: any) {
    super();
    if (itemData) {
      this.uuid = itemData.uuid;
      this.description = itemData.description;
      this.name = itemData.name;
      this.price = itemData.price;
      this.image = itemData.image;
      this.quantity = itemData.quantity;
      this.data = itemData.data;
    }
  }

  static fromJSON(itemData: any) {
    return new TourCartItem(itemData.uuid);
  }


  getId(): any {
    return this.uuid;
  }

  setId(id: any): void {
    this.uuid = id;
  }

  getDescription(): any {
    return this.description;
  }

  setDescription(description: any): any {
    this.description = description;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  setName(name: string): void {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getPrice(): number {
    return this.price;
  }

  setPrice(price: number): void {
    this.price = price;
  }

  getQuantity(): number {
    return this.quantity;
  }

  setQuantity(quantity: number): void {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  getImage(): string {
    return this.image;
  }

  setImage(image: string): void {
    this.image = image;
  }

  getData(): any {
    return this.data;
  }

  setData(data: any): void {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Can someone help, maybe trying to install this library?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some more code my guess you should use LocalStorageCartService class to make it work

Comment: @PascalL. i've addedd more code. Please can you explain me what is LocalStorageCartService? I didn't add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, the issue was that my custom ItemCart dont have correct *fromJSON* implementation.